# How to open/use crafting in rising world?

Tags: rising-world

o/, just landed, it's freezing!!

I wish to make a campfire, but can't figure out how to even open the crafting window.

tyvm for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out in the end:

Press 'I' for inventory, than in the tabs, select 'Crafting'

Hope it helps ..